# Creating Sort by high/low price list for store products?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

Here's a sample of my HTML, but obviously shortened:

```
<h2 class="price">$881.99</h2>
<h2 class="price">$715.05</h2>
<h2 class="price">$651.95</h2>
<h2 class="price">$921.10</h2>
```

And my JavaScript thanks to a user on here helping me, it removes the $ and sorts the prices, then logs to console, as you can see.

```
function myFunction() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("price"))
        .map(function(el){
            return Number(el.innerHTML.replace(/\$/, ""));
        })
        .sort();
}

console.log(myFunction());
```

The thing is, it works fine when I use a Fiddle, but not when I try to implement it to my actual website, the array is empty.

So basically I'm wondering how to actually output the sorted items to the screen, and how to reverse the sort order in `myFunction`?

Comment: You may be calling your function before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example. You can reverse the sorting order by passing a function as the first parameter for `.sort()` which tells JavaScript which item comes first. Here I've swapped `a` and `b` in the `return` statement of that function, which reverses the sorting order. Then, using a simple loop, I append the elements back to their parent in the new order.

What you were missing is the last part, you didn't add the sorted elements back into the document, they were left in memory after the sorting finished and nothing happened to them.

```js
function myFunction(){
  var elements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("price"));
  elements.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseFloat(b.innerHTML.substring(1)) - parseFloat(a.innerHTML.substring(1));
  });
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].parentNode.appendChild(elements[i]);
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<h2 class="price">$881.99</h2>
<h2 class="price">$715.05</h2>
<h2 class="price">$651.95</h2>
<h2 class="price">$921.10</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way，

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2 class="price">$881.99</h2>
    <h2 class="price">$715.05</h2>
    <h2 class="price">$651.95</h2>
    <h2 class="price">$921.10</h2>
    <script>
        var array = Array.slice(document.getElementsByClassName("price"));
        array.sort(function (a, b) {            
            return parseFloat(a.innerHTML.replace("$", "")) - parseFloat(b.innerHTML.replace("$", ""));
        });
        array.map(function(e){
           e.parentNode.appendChild(e); 
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is used to reverse the array.

```
<body>
<h2 class="price">$881.99</h2>
<h2 class="price">$715.05</h2>
<h2 class="price">$651.95</h2>
<h2 class="price">$921.10</h2>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var temp;
     temp = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("price"))
        .map(function(el)
        {
            temp = Number(el.innerHTML.replace(/\$/, ""));
            return temp;
        })
        .sort();
    return temp.reverse();
}
console.log(myFunction());  
</script>

</body>
```